# Dagre.js draw edge from a child node to a parent node: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘rank’ of undefined

Tags: subgraph, dagre-d3, dagre

I am currently using dagre.js for my visualisation project. This library is great.

I got to a point where I need to create nested graphs, so a node(s) can be contained within another node (parent), I am able to do that. But I am unable to draw an edge from a child node to a parent node, whenever I've tried to do so I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘rank’ of undefined.

I have no idea what is causing that, but if you can help please do.

Much appreciated,
Michael